# C++ No matching function for call to 'Nodo::Nodo()'

Tags: c++

Good morning.

I'm trying to implement a graph in c++ with nodes and edges memorized as lists. I'm italian so: graph/Grafo , edge/Arco , node/Nodo , listEdges/ListaArchi, listNodes/ListaNodi.

This is my code:

Grafo.h

```
#ifndef GRAFO_H_
#define GRAFO_H_
#include "ListaNodi.h"

class Grafo {
public:
    Grafo();
    virtual ~Grafo();
    void leggiGrafo(std::string nomeFile);
    void aggiungiNodo(std::string nomeNodo);
private:
    std::string nomeGrafo;
    ListaNodi nodi;
};

#endif /* GRAFO_H_ */
```

Grafo.cpp

```
#include "Grafo.h"

Grafo::Grafo() {
}

Grafo::~Grafo() {
}

void Grafo::aggiungiNodo(std::string nomeNodo) {
}

void Grafo::leggiGrafo(std::string nomeFile){
}
```

Arco.h

```
#ifndef ARCO_H_
#define ARCO_H_
#include <string>
#include "Nodo.h"

class Arco {
public:
    Arco();
    virtual ~Arco();
    Arco *next;
    std::string style;
    std::string color;
private:
    Nodo primo;
    Nodo secondo;
};

#endif /* ARCO_H_ */
```

Arco.cpp (Here is where the problem is:

Arco.cpp:10:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Nodo::Nodo()'

```
#include "Arco.h"

Arco::Arco() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    next = NULL;
}

Arco::~Arco() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Nodo.h

Other problem here:

Nodo.h:15:2: error: extra qualification 'Nodo::' on member 'Nodo' [-fpermissive]

```
#ifndef NODO_H_
#define NODO_H_
#include <string>
#include "ListaArchi.h"

class Nodo {
public:
    Nodo::Nodo(std::string nome);
    virtual ~Nodo();
    void setColore(std::string colore);
    ListaArchi listaArchi;
    Nodo *next;
private:
    std::string colore;
    std::string nome;
    std::string label;
};

#endif /* NODO_H_ */
```

Nodo.cpp

```
#include "Nodo.h"
#include <string>

Nodo::Nodo(std::string nome) {
    this->nome = nome;
    this->colore = "white";
    next=NULL;
}

Nodo::~Nodo() {

}
```

Arco.h

Other problem here:

ListaArchi.h:16:2: error: 'Arco' does not name a type

```
#ifndef LISTAARCHI_H_
#define LISTAARCHI_H_
#include "Arco.h"

class ListaArchi {
public:
    ListaArchi();
    virtual ~ListaArchi();
    Arco arco;
};

#endif /* LISTAARCHI_H_ */
```

ListaArchi.cpp

```
#include "ListaArchi.h"

ListaArchi::ListaArchi() {

}

ListaArchi::~ListaArchi() {

}
```

ListaNodi.h

```
#ifndef LISTANODI_H_
#define LISTANODI_H_
#include "Nodo.h"

class ListaNodi {
public:
    ListaNodi();
    virtual ~ListaNodi();
    Nodo nodo;
};

#endif /* LISTANODI_H_ */
```

ListaNodi.cpp

```
#include "ListaNodi.h"

ListaNodi::ListaNodi() {
    nodo = NULL;
}

ListaNodi::~ListaNodi() {

}
```

Could anyone help me with these problems?

Comment: You don't have a default constructor for `Nodo` but it is required elsewhere (e.g. in `ListaNodi`)..

Comment: remove Nodo:: inside class body

Comment: You also have circular dependencies between your classes. (That's the reason for "'Arco' does not name a type".) There are many answered questions on SO about how to solve that problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to implement this using list of nodes/arcs? Why not simply store these in vectors and have pointers to the nodes in your arc?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems. One is that in your `ListaNodi` class use the `Nodi` class to declare an object `nodo`. That will use the *default constructor* of `Nodi`, but you haven't declared or defined one. Only a constructor taking a string.

The simple solution for the above is to create a `Nodi` default constructor, i.e. a constructor taking no arguments.

Another problem is in the `ListaNodi` constructor implementation, where you do

```
nodo = NULL;
```

Here you treat `nodo` as a pointer, which it isn't. The solution to this is to remove that line, and instead use a constructor initializer list:

```
ListaNodi::ListaNodi()
    : nodo{}
{
}
```

Of course, that requires you to have fixed the first problem above, by creating a default constructor.

Furthermore inside the class definition of `Nodo` you declare the (non-default) constructor using scoping, which is not needed.

Plain

```
Nodo(std::string nome);
```

is all you need.

Finally you have the problem with a circular header-file dependency, where `ListaArchi` depends on `Arco` which depends on `Nodo` which depends on `ListaArchi`. You need to find a way to break that header-file dependency circle. The simplest way to break such a circle is to use pointers somewhere, and forward declaration of the type instead of including the header file.

---

It seems that you are making lists, which means you can very easily break the header-file circular dependency by making the "nodes" in the list classes being pointers, something which they probably should be from the beginning. That will actually solve the two first problems I mentioned as well.

Then the `ListaArchi.h` header file could look like this:

```
#ifndef LISTAARCHI_H_
#define LISTAARCHI_H_

class Arco;  // Forward declaration instead of header file inclusion

class ListaArchi {
public:
    ListaArchi();
    virtual ~ListaArchi();
    Arco* arco;  // Declares as a pointer
};

#endif /* LISTAARCHI_H_ */
```

And `ListaNode.h` should look like

```
#ifndef LISTANODI_H_
#define LISTANODI_H_

class Nodo;  // Forward declaration instead of header file inclusion

class ListaNodi {
public:
    ListaNodi();
    virtual ~ListaNodi();
    Nodo* nodo;  // Declare as a pointer
};

#endif /* LISTANODI_H_ */
```

Finally your `ListaNodi` constructor makes more sense with the `NULL` assignment, but I suggest you still use construction initializer lists:

```
ListaNodi::ListaNodi()
    : nodo{nullptr}
{
}
```